# Are bootstrap outline styles accessible by default?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, accessibility

Let's say I'm using the latest bootstrap. I have my primary color sass variable set to black, so that would mean the default button outline color would be
`rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)`, which [does not pass WCAG 2.0](https://contrast-ratio.com/#rgba%280%2C0%2C0%2C.25-on-white). Should I override bootstrap's default outline styles for more accessible ones, or does the color contrast of outlines not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color contrast always matters, whether it is the outlines or any other graphical element of the user interface.

For people using their keyboard to navigate through pages elements and focus them, and who only use visual indication (i.e. not screen readers), developers have to provide some visual hint to let them know the element is focused.

If you change a focused element background color to be visually identified, then outline will not really matter. But if you don't address `focus` state styles, you should rely on the outline for the `focus` state styles. In this case, you need to make sure `outline` styles passe the accessibility tests.

Comment: Thank you! What about shadows on elements? Can I put super light shadows on elements (like in the header of stack overflow)?

Comment: I'd say shadows can be useful to maintain a visible delimitation between elements. The stackoverflow header example you gave falls in this category and –aesthetics put apart– helps highlighting the header, becaus SO use lines and borders here and there.
Note that this may not be necessary on websites that don't use any borders (or lines) at all, but the question you should ask yourself is "Is everyone able to distinguish this element?".
Asking this kind of questions is IMHO the first step toward accessible websites.

Comment: I think most shadows don't have sufficient contrast with their backgrounds. Does it matter?